# Swift: how to avoid performing versions checks

Tags: swift, macos, swift-package-manager

I am building a Swift library. In my library, I define a struct which contains a `DateInterval`.

```
struct A {
    let date = DateInterval()
}
```

However, when attempting to build my library, I receive the following error:

> `'DateInterval'` is only available on OS X 10.12 or newer'

So I added an `@available(OSX 10.12, *)` attribute to the struct.

The problem is now, whenever I create an instance of the struct, I am forced to perform a version check:

```
if #available(OSX 10.12, *) {
    let foo = A()
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

I do not need my library to run on versions of macOS prior to 10.12; is there any way to indicate this to the compiler so that I do not have to perform cumbersome version checks each time I use this struct?

Answer (score 3):

You should **change the deployment target** of your library to macOS 10.12 inside your project's settings.

[image: Deployment Target changed to 10.12]

Comment: I'm surprised this question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: It might be one. Although I am not in favor of answering obvious duplicates, the question is asked in such a form that it can be answered in a non-duped way.

Comment: I'm surprised this question hasn't dozens of upvotes.